# Blazor Java script interop

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I have this javascript library that is written in TypeScript

```
(function(f) {
    if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module !== "undefined") {
        module.exports = f()
    } else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
        define([], f)
    } else {
        var g;
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            g = window
        } else if (typeof global !== "undefined") {
            g = global
        } else if (typeof self !== "undefined") {
            g = self
        } else {
            g = this
        }
        g.richTextEditor = f()
    }
}
)(function() {
    var define, module, exports;
    return (function() {
        function r(e, n, t) {
            function o(i, f) {
                if (!n[i]) {
                    if (!e[i]) {
                        var c = "function" == typeof require && require;
                        if (!f && c)
                            return c(i, !0);
                        if (u)
                            return u(i, !0);
                        var a = new Error("Cannot find module '" + i + "'");
                        throw a.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND",
                        a
                    }
                    var p = n[i] = {
                        exports: {}
                    };
                    e[i][0].call(p.exports, function(r) {
                        var n = e[i][1][r];
                        return o(n || r)
                    }, p, p.exports, r, e, n, t)
                }
                return n[i].exports
            }
            for (var u = "function" == typeof require && require, i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
                o(t[i]);
            return o
        }
        return r
    }
    )()({
        1: [function(require, module, exports) {
            "use strict";
            Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
                value: true
            });
            exports.showHello = void 0;
            const greet_1 = require("./greet");
            function showHello(divName, name) {
                const elt = document.getElementById(divName);
                elt.innerText = (0,
                greet_1.sayHello)(name);
            }
            exports.showHello = showHello;

        }
        , {
            "./greet": 2
        }],
        2: [function(require, module, exports) {
            "use strict";
            Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
                value: true
            });
            exports.sayHello = void 0;
            function sayHello(compiler) {
                return `Hello from ${compiler}`;
            }
            exports.sayHello = sayHello;

        }
        , {}]
    }, {}, [1])(1)
});
```

and I am trying to execute showHello function in this library using JSInterop in Blazor using following code

```
public class TypeScriptInterop
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<IJSObjectReference>> _moduleTask;

    public TypeScriptInterop(IJSRuntime jsRuntime)
    {
        _moduleTask = new(()=>
        jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./_content/Blazored.RichTextEditor/js/bundle.generated.js").AsTask());
    }

    public async ValueTask TsButtonClicked()
    {
        var javaScript = await _moduleTask.Value;
        if (_moduleTask.IsValueCreated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Captured Js");
        }
        await javaScript.InvokeVoidAsync("richTextEditor.showHello", "greeting", "Ubhaya");
    }
}
```

when I run this I get the error message saying

> WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'richTextEditor.showHello' ('richTextEditor' was undefined).

but if I use `<script src="./_content/Blazored.RichTextEditor/js/bundle.generated.js"></script>` inside the index.html in blazor wasm project. it works correctly.

I am trying to create a Blazor component library. is there a way to do this in my current approach since I want to use JS isolation.

Comment: If I remember correctly your JS code has to be exported as an ES Module in order for JS Isolation to work. Not 100% sure but I can't see any other reason why your code should not work so that's where I would start to look.

Comment: I am very beginner for typescript. I follow this article https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html to compile to javascript.  It provided the quoted javascript code

Comment: Unfortunately I don't  work with JS/TS often enough to be able to tell you how to transform one type of module into another. But since most of the js code you provided is just plumbing code, rewriting the actual functionality in a simple ES Module should be trivial.

Comment: My question here would be: where did you find this lazy `moduleTask` approach that seemingly imports a JavaScript bundle when a button is clicked? Never seen such a thing. Also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet does not document this. The solution here would surely be to add the js file to the `head` section of your html page or any other supported location, so that it is correctly loaded when you open the page.

Comment: Lazy ModuleTask is using default template provided by the Microsoft for dotnet 7.  Not sure in dotnet 6. Also mentioned and used in this video. https://www.youtube.com/live/I_zFlBKgl5s?feature=share